# esper detect change in value of Event

Tags: sql, complex-event-processing, esper, nesper

Hej!
I have a small problem with my esper code. The input is like that:

```
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Temp', value =1}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Press', value =1}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Speed', value =1}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Temp', value =2}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Press', value =2}

t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Speed', value =2}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Press', value =1}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Press', value =1}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Temp', value =3}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
CondiA ={varible ='Press', value =1}
```

I have one type of Events which has a variable name and a value.
I want to detect changes in the values of one specific variable.
so I need a select statement which gives me the data at :

- second 4 (Temp changed from 1->2)
- second 5 (Press changed from 1->2)
- second 6 (Speed changed from 1->2)
- second 7 (Press changed from 2->1)
- second 9 (Temp changed from 2->3)

I tried diffeent stuff with `prior`and `prev`but nothing works properly.
This is the most plausible one I made, but it does not give me the results I with for. I tried it with a pattern, but I get a memory overload with @SuppressOverlappingMatches.

```
select value as x from CondiA#unique(varible) as A where  prior(1, A.value) != A.value AND varible = (select varible from CondiA()#lastevent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly each "varible" partition is independent and within each value "varible" you need "prior"?

You can do this with a context like so

```
create context PerVarible partition by varible from CondiA;
context PerVarible select value as x from CondiA where prior(1, A.value) != A.value;
```

Notes,

- no need for a data window, "prior" operates without one
- "prev" could be used instead of "prior" and with a grouped-window, see docs, in which case you wouldn't need to partition